# CheckerFramework for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, checker-framework

Is there something like [CheckerFramework](https://checkerframework.org) for TypeScript? I would like to be able to use annotations to find code problems at compile time, like `@Nullable` on a parameter which you immediately called a function upon.

Comment: Typescript has strict nullability checking under the `strictNullChecks` compiler flag. Generally types should be what you use to get the compiler to report compile time errors ..

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no. There's no way to alter TypeScript's behavior by annotation/pragma. However, as @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir commented, there's a `strictNullChecks` compilerOptions.

I setup a [DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20toString(target%3F%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20target.toString()%20%2F%2F%20target%20is%20possibly%20%60undefined%60%2C%20should%20warn%20you%20here%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20toString2(target%3F%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!target)%20return%20''%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20target.toString()%20%2F%2F%20no%20warning%20here%2C%20smart%20enough%20to%20know%20things%20taken%20cared%20%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20toString3(target%3F%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20target!.toString()%20%2F%2F%20manually%20turn%20off%20nullable%20check%20with%20%60!%60%0A%7D%0A) of this feature in TypeScript playground. Remember to click the `Options` blue button, and check the `strictNullChecks` in dropdown.